# ASP.NET Core MVC - Recommended way for multiple model in one view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I just want to ask what is recommended way for implementing two models in one view? Or is there any better way for complex view. I want to know highly recommended way. I have an idea about this just like this one here... https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/ <-- But I'm thinking if is this really recommended for complex system such as inventory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases there is a high possibility that you want to reload/refresh some parts of the view. Therefore you should split the view into partial views. Each partial view has its own model. So when initially loading a view you can create a viewmodel which aggregates the models for the different partials. So in the main view you can render the partials by passing the model from viewmodel as an parameter. If you have to refresh some partial views with ajax, you can call an action which returns your partial view filled with the model for this view.
I would not recommend ViewBag or ViewData because you always have to type check/cast objects.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer and effort. Just as I thought it's not recommended to use viewbag or viewdata for complex system. Thanks again.