# Combining two models in one view ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app with view model only displays data of one model name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, viewmodel

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application. I have created two models (alongside other models which are irrelevant to my question) and each one has their own properties (not going to mention those properties here because it isn't helpful that much).

Long story short, after a thorough research on Google and from everywhere else, I came up with this conclusion that for I want, I need to create a view model (Let's call it `CompositeModel`).

Here's the code:

```
using Project_Name.Models;

namespace Project_Name.ViewModels
{
    public class CompositeModel
    {
        public ShoArt? ShAr { get; set; }
        public FarSho? FaSh { get; set; }
        public List<string>? ShArColumns { get; set; }
        public List<string>? FaShColumns { get; set; }
        public List<string>? SelectedColumns { get; set; }
        public List<ShoArt>? ShArData { get; set; }
        public List<FarSho>? FaShData { get; set; }
        public string? SelectedModelName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Briefly explaining, what I want is kinda an advanced filtering through two models that we have (probably going to add more models to it in the future but for now, only two models).

The user is going to observe all columns of those two models listed for them from the database and they can select which one they want to see in the result page by checking or unchecking their checkboxes but the whole purpose is joining the columns of these two models with each other.

**Note**: not sure if it's gonna help but later on, the user has to be able to do some queries on these data by implementing their own custom condition to get exactly those data fit with their demands. For example, choosing the range of "Age" column if there's a column with that name in any of our selected tables (models). Like telling our web app: "I want only those people from 30 to 40 years old" or something like that.

Here's our `Index.cshtml` code for our `FilterController` which is responsible for displaying all the columns of these two models:

```
@model Project_Name.ViewModels.CompositeModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Display Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Data Display</h1>

    <form method="post" asp-action="DisplayTable">
        <h2>Select Model</h2>
        <label>
            Select Model:
            <select name="SelectedModelName">
                <option value="ShAr">ShAr</option>
                <option value="FaSh">FaSh</option>
                <!-- Add other model options as needed -->
            </select>
        </label>

        <h2>Select Columns</h2>
        <label>
            ShAr:
            @foreach (var column in Model.ShArColumns!)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" name="selectedColumns" value="ShAr.@column" /> @column
            }
        </label>

        <label>
            FaSh:
            @foreach (var column in Model.FaShColumns!)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" name="selectedColumns" value="FaSh.@column" /> @column
            }
        </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Display Table" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the `FilterController`'s code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using yadegaranAlpha.Context;
using System.Linq;
using yadegaranAlpha.Models;
using yadegaranAlpha.ViewModels;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using NuGet.Protocol.Plugins;
//using AspNetCore;

namespace Project_Name.Controllers
{
    public class FilterController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public FilterController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var shArColumns = GetPropertyNames<ShoArt>();
            var faShColumns = GetPropertyNames<FarSho>();

            var compositeModel = new CompositeModel
            {
                ShArColumns = shArColumns,
                FaShColumns = faShColumns,

                // Initially empty, will be populated based 
                // on user selection
                SelectedColumns = new List<string>() 
            };

            return View(compositeModel);
        }

        // Helper method to get property names of a type
        private List<string> GetPropertyNames<T>()
        {
            return typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
        }

        //DisplayTable ActionResult

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DisplayTable(CompositeModel model)
        {
            model.SelectedColumns = model.SelectedColumns ?? new List<string>();

            List<object> combinedData = new List<object>();

            var shArData = await _context.shoart.ToListAsync();
            var faShData = await _context.farsho.ToListAsync();

            foreach (var item in shArData)
            {
                combinedData.Add(item);
            }

            foreach (var item in faShData)
            {
                combinedData.Add(item);
            }

            model.ShArData = shArData;
            model.FaShData = faShData;

            return View("DisplayTable", model);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here's the code for `DisplayTable.cshtml` file responsible for displaying the selected columns and their data for us:

```
@using System.ComponentModel;
@model Project_Name.ViewModels.CompositeModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Display Table";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Display Table</title>
    <!-- Include any necessary styles or scripts here -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Customized Data Display</h1>

    <table class="table table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var column in Model.SelectedColumns)
                {
                    <th>@column</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.SelectedModelName == "ShAr" && Model.ShArData != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.ShArData)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var column in Model.SelectedColumns)
                        {
                            <td>@GetColumnValue(item, column)</td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            }
            else if (Model.SelectedModelName == "FaSh" && Model.FaShData != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.FaShData)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var column in Model.SelectedColumns)
                        {
                            <td>@GetColumnValue(item, column)</td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    @functions {
        public string GetColumnValue(object item, string columnName)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                return "";
            }

            try
            {
                // Extract the actual property name from the full columnName
                var actualPropertyName = columnName.Split('.').LastOrDefault();

                var property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(item).Find(actualPropertyName, true);
                if (property != null)
                {
                    var value = property.GetValue(item);

                    // Log the values for debugging
                    Console.WriteLine($"Property: {actualPropertyName}, Value: {value}");

                    return value?.ToString() ?? "";
                }

                return "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the exception
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
                return "";
            }
        }
    }

</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem?

The problem is that when I select FaSh modelName, it's only gonna display data for that modelName and the other modelName's data (in this case, it's ShAr) display empty data cells and vice-versa.
Just pay attention to pictures below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9DcJ.png)

In the picture above, I've selected those columns from these two models that I want. (Other columns have been hidden with red lines).

And the picture below, in its result when user clicks on Display Table button. Just keep in mind that for security reasons, I've tried to hide data but you can trust me and that part with red rectangle contains data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CNju.png)

As you can see, because our selected modelName was ShAr, therefore only data related to ShAr modelName are gonna get displayed and vice-versa.
I can do the same thing with FaSh modelName and this time data of those columns related to that modelName are gonna get displayed.

I want both of them get displayed without any problem.
I don't know but It's like in ASP.NET CORE we can only select one modelName in one view, unfortunately and if I only could mix these two models in our final result View, then I wouldn't have had any problem dealing with.

How to deal with this issue in my app?

I've also tried these resources and none of them revolve around my issue.

[Use multiple models in one view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71892446/use-multiple-models-in-one-view)

[Two models in one view in ASP MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550627/two-models-in-one-view-in-asp-mvc-3)

[MVC Multiple Models in One View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925122/mvc-multiple-models-in-one-view)

[ASP.NET Core MVC - Recommended way for multiple model in one view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67309673/asp-net-core-mvc-recommended-way-for-multiple-model-in-one-view)

and so many other resources.

Let me provide you more details that might be useful to know.
My ShAr table have 1170 records and my FaSh table has 2456 on the other hand.
Honestly, it doesn't make sense to display these two tables next to each other as long as their records number is not equal.
FaSh table is connected to ShAr table by a foreign key.
I don't know where I'm going wrong but I need help to understand the logic for implementing what I want.
So far, I've created this which isn't enough and not doing the job.

I really really appreciate any help and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

According to your description, there are some more details:

1. The shoart and farsho is one-to-many
2. You need conditions optional when checkbox checked
3. The purpose of your option of selectedModelName still unclear

You can check my sample to give more details. Now see the demo to check if it fits your demand.

[image]

> 1. CompositeModel

```
using CombineModel.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace CombineModel.ViewModels
{
    public class CompositeModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ShoArt? ShAr { get; set; }
        public FarSho? FaSh { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<string>? ShArColumns { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<string>? FaShColumns { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<string>? SelectedColumns { get; set; }
        public List<ShoArt>? ShArData { get; set; }
        public List<FarSho>? FaShData { get; set; }
        public string? SelectedModelName { get; set; }

        //added properties used for conditions in pages
        //ShoArt model conditions
        public string? ShoArtNameContains { get; set; }
        public int? ShoIdFrom { get; set; }
        public int? ShoIdTo { get; set; }
        public bool IncludeShoName { get; set; }
        public bool IncludeShoId { get; set; }
        //FarSho model conditions
        public string? FarShoNameContains { get; set; }
        public int? FarIdFrom { get; set; }
        public int? FarIdTo { get; set; }
        public bool IncludeFarName { get; set; }
        public bool IncludeFarId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> 2.FarSho model

```
namespace CombineModel.Models
{
    public class FarSho
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? FarName { get; set; }
        public string? FarDescription { get; set; }
        public int ShoArtId { get; set; }
        public ShoArt ShoArts { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

> 3.ShoArt model

```
namespace CombineModel.Models
{
    public class ShoArt
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? ShoName { get; set; }
        public string? ShoDescription { get; set; }
        public ICollection<FarSho> FarShos { get; } = new List<FarSho>();
    }
}
```

> 4. Index.cshtml

```
@model CompositeModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Display Data</title>
    @* some style *@
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .composite-section {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .composite-label {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .composite-input {
            display: none;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .composite-checkbox {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Data Display</h1>

    <form method="post" asp-action="DisplayTable">
        <h2>Select Model</h2>
        <label>
            Select Model:
            <select name="SelectedModelName">
                <option value="ShAr">ShAr</option>
                <option value="FaSh">FaSh</option>
                <!-- Add other model options as needed -->
            </select>
        </label>

        <h2>Select Columns</h2>
        <label>
            ShAr:
            @foreach (var column in Model.ShArColumns!)
            {
                //filter logic of ShoArt property
                if (column == "ShoName")
                {
                    <div class="composite-section">
                        <label class="composite-label">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   value="ShAr.@column"
                                   name="selectedColumns"
                                   class="composite-checkbox"
                                   onclick="document.getElementById('shoNameContainsInput').style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';" />
                            @column
                        </label>
                        <div id="shoNameContainsInput" class="composite-input">
                            <input type="text" name="ShoArtNameContains" value="@Model.ShoArtNameContains" placeholder="Enter name contains..." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                else if (column == "Id")
                {
                    <div class="composite-section">
                        <label class="composite-label">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   value="ShAr.@column"
                                   name="selectedColumns"
                                   class="composite-checkbox"
                                   onclick="var display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
                            document.getElementById('shoIdFromInput').style.display = display;
                            document.getElementById('shoIdToInput').style.display = display;" />
                            @column
                        </label>
                        <div id="shoIdFromInput" class="composite-input">
                            <input type="number" name="ShoIdFrom" value="@Model.ShoIdFrom" placeholder="Id from..." />
                        </div>
                        <div id="shoIdToInput" class="composite-input">
                            <input type="number" name="ShoIdTo" value="@Model.ShoIdTo" placeholder="Id to..." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                //Some other properties conditions as you wish
                //...
                else
                {
                    <div class="composite-section">
                        <label class="composite-label">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="composite-checkbox" name="selectedColumns" value="ShAr.@column" /> @column
                        </label>
                    </div>
                }
            }
            FaSh:
            @foreach (var column in Model.FaShColumns!)
            {
                //filter logic of FarSho property
                if (column == "FarName")
                {
                    <div class="composite-section">
                        <label class="composite-label">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   value="FaSh.@column"
                                   name="selectedColumns"
                                   class="composite-checkbox"
                                   onclick="document.getElementById('farNameContainsInput').style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';" />
                            @column
                        </label>
                        <div id="farNameContainsInput" class="composite-input">
                            <input type="text" name="FarShoNameContains" value="@Model.FarShoNameContains" placeholder="Enter name contains..." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                else if (column == "Id")
                {
                    <div class="composite-section">
                        <label class="composite-label">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   value="FaSh.@column"
                                   name="selectedColumns"
                                   class="composite-checkbox"
                                   onclick="var display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
                            document.getElementById('farIdFromInput').style.display = display;
                            document.getElementById('farIdToInput').style.display = display;" />
                            @column
                        </label>
                        <div id="farIdFromInput" class="composite-input">
                            <input type="number" name="FarIdFrom" value="@Model.FarIdFrom" placeholder="Id from..." />
                        </div>
                        <div id="farIdToInput" class="composite-input">
                            <input type="number" name="FarIdTo" value="@Model.FarIdTo" placeholder="Id to..." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
                //Some other properties conditions as you wish
                //...
                else
                {
                    <div class="composite-section">
                        <label class="composite-label">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="composite-checkbox" name="selectedColumns" value="FaSh.@column" /> @column
                        </label>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </label>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Display Table" />
    </form>

    <!-- The rest of your view with the table goes here -->

    <script>
        // If you want to maintain the state of the checkboxes after the form is submitted and the page is reloaded:
        window.onload = function () {
            var nameCheckbox = document.querySelector("input[name='IncludeName']");
            var ageCheckbox = document.querySelector("input[name='IncludeId']");

            document.getElementById('farNameContainsInput').style.display = nameCheckbox.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
            document.getElementById('shoNameContainsInput').style.display = nameCheckbox.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
            var display = ageCheckbox.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
            document.getElementById('shoIdFromInput').style.display = display;
            document.getElementById('shoIdToInput').style.display = display;
            document.getElementById('farIdFromInput').style.display = display;
            document.getElementById('farIdToInput').style.display = display;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> 5. DisplayTable.cshtml

```
@using System.ComponentModel;
@model CompositeModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Display Table";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Display Table</title>
    <!-- Include any necessary styles or scripts here -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Customized Data Display</h1>

    <table class="table table-sm">
        @if (Model.ShArData != null && Model.FaShData != null)
        {
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var column in Model.SelectedColumns)
                    {
                        if (column.Split('.').FirstOrDefault() == "ShAr")
                        {
                            <th>@column.Split('.').LastOrDefault()</th>
                        }
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.ShArData)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var column in Model.SelectedColumns)
                        {
                            if (column.Split('.').FirstOrDefault() == "ShAr")
                            {
                                <td>@GetColumnValue(item, column)</td>
                            }
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var column in Model.SelectedColumns)
                    {
                        if (column.Split('.').FirstOrDefault() == "FaSh")
                        {
                            <th>@column.Split('.').LastOrDefault()</th>
                        } 
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.FaShData)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var column in Model.SelectedColumns)
                        {
                            if (column.Split('.').FirstOrDefault() == "FaSh")
                            {
                                <td>@GetColumnValue(item, column)</td>
                            }
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        }
       
    </table>

    @functions {
        public string GetColumnValue(object item, string columnName)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                return "";
            }

            try
            {
                // Extract the actual property name from the full columnName
                var actualPropertyName = columnName.Split('.').LastOrDefault();

                var property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(item).Find(actualPropertyName, true);
                if (property != null)
                {
                    var value = property.GetValue(item);

                    // Log the values for debugging
                    Console.WriteLine($"Property: {actualPropertyName}, Value: {value}");

                    return value?.ToString() ?? "";
                }

                return "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the exception
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
                return "";
            }
        }
    }

</body>
</html>
```

> 6.FilterController

```
    //DisplayTable ActionResult
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DisplayTable(CompositeModel model)
    {
        model.SelectedColumns = model.SelectedColumns ?? new List<string>();

        var query = _context.ShoArt.AsQueryable();

        //1.Custom Filter ShoArt Logic
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.ShoArtNameContains))
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.ShoName.Contains(model.ShoArtNameContains));
        }
        if (model.ShoIdFrom.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.Id >= model.ShoIdFrom.Value);
        }
        if (model.ShoIdTo.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.Id <= model.ShoIdTo.Value);
        }
        var shArData = await query.ToListAsync();

        //2.New a list to filter the FarSho model
        List<int> shids = new List<int>();
        foreach (var f in shArData)
        {
            shids.Add(f.Id);
        }

        //3.Custom Filter FarSho Logic
        var queryF = _context.FarSho.AsQueryable();
        queryF = queryF.Where(p => shids.Contains(p.ShoArtId));
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.FarShoNameContains))
        {
            queryF = queryF.Where(p => p.FarName.Contains(model.FarShoNameContains));
        }
        if (model.FarIdFrom.HasValue)
        {
            queryF = queryF.Where(p => p.Id >= model.FarIdFrom.Value);
        }
        if (model.FarIdTo.HasValue)
        {
            queryF = queryF.Where(p => p.Id <= model.FarIdTo.Value);
        }
        var faShData = await queryF.ToListAsync();

        model.ShArData = shArData;
        model.FaShData = faShData;

        return View("DisplayTable", model);
    }
```

---

It is a judgement code mistake. Your code part of displaying the model properties **“foreach (var item in Model.ShArData){}”** only retrieve one model in your judgement, that’s why you cannot display the other model in your table.

Since your judge of SelectedModelName makes no sense in this scenario, I remove the judge and please consider the judge later in your app. And you also mentioned that it doesn't make sense to display these two tables next to each other, I display the table this way.

> The DisplayTable view

```
@using System.ComponentModel;
@model CompositeModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Display Table";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Display Table</title>
    <!-- Include any necessary styles or scripts here -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Customized Data Display</h1>

    <table class="table table-sm">
        @if (Model.ShArData != null && Model.FaShData != null)
        {
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var column in Model.SelectedColumns)
                    {
                        if (column.Split('.').FirstOrDefault() == "ShAr")
                        {
                            <th>@column.Split('.').LastOrDefault()</th>
                        }
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.ShArData)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var column in Model.SelectedColumns)
                        {
                            if (column.Split('.').FirstOrDefault() == "ShAr")
                            {
                                <td>@GetColumnValue(item, column)</td>
                            }
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var column in Model.SelectedColumns)
                    {
                        if (column.Split('.').FirstOrDefault() == "FaSh")
                        {
                            <th>@column.Split('.').LastOrDefault()</th>
                        } 
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.FaShData)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var column in Model.SelectedColumns)
                        {
                            if (column.Split('.').FirstOrDefault() == "FaSh")
                            {
                                <td>@GetColumnValue(item, column)</td>
                            }
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        }
       
    </table>

    @functions {
        public string GetColumnValue(object item, string columnName)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                return "";
            }

            try
            {
                // Extract the actual property name from the full columnName
                var actualPropertyName = columnName.Split('.').LastOrDefault();

                var property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(item).Find(actualPropertyName, true);
                if (property != null)
                {
                    var value = property.GetValue(item);

                    // Log the values for debugging
                    Console.WriteLine($"Property: {actualPropertyName}, Value: {value}");

                    return value?.ToString() ?? "";
                }

                return "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the exception
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
                return "";
            }
        }
    }

</body>
</html>
```

Other code remains the same.

Test

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Ronaldoz. It's actually reading data from both of our models but there's only one issue that I wish I could solve it. Otherwise, reading data in this way wouldn't do that much help to me because of numerous data that we have in these two tables.
I wish we could see the result in only one table OR we could have conditions on these fields before we select our columns and display them in our DisplayTable view. Too many data will be shown and it's not ideal for sure. How to handle this?
Anyway, I'm gonna accept this as the right answer but I still need help to finish this.